# How to get text of each cell from 1st 2 rows of ag-grid in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, ui-automation

I have an angular grid with 3 rows. All three rows come under same class A. but ever row has it xpath webelement B (//div). How to iterate through each cell of 1st two rows and get the values in an array? Please help me in this.

There is no repeater. When I tried using getting text of each cell of 1st row using div xpath webelement B then it is giving me result like this:

```
cell1
cell2
cell3
```

But I need result in this format

```
['cell1', 'cell2', 'cell3']
```

and when I get text of class A then it is giving me in proper format but all the cells of 3 rows are coming. like ['cell1', 'cell2', 'cell3', 'cell6'........]

I have written like this:

```
var expectedCells = element.all(by.css('.A); - using class A
expectedCells.each((eachCell) => {
    eachCell.getText().then((cellText) => {
        expect(expectedCells).toEqual([['cell1', 'cell2', 'cell3'])
    });
})
```

Expected: ['cell1', 'cell2', 'cell3']

Actual: giving me last cell text only

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with less lines, using map:

```
let elements = element.all(by.css('.A'));

elements.map(el => el && el.getText()).then( textarray => {
    expect(textarray).toEqual(['cell1', 'cell2', 'cell3']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What is this el you in your code? Are we interating through each row in this?

Comment: for map you can read more here: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
var expectedArray[] = ['cell1', 'cell2', 'cell3'];
var expectedCells = element.all(by.css('.A); - using class A
var textArray[];
for(i=0;i<expectedCells.count();i++){
    expectedCells.get(i).getText().then((cellText) => {
    textArray[i]= cellText;
 });
}
expect(textArray).toBe(expectedArray);
```

Hope the above code helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried somewhat similat and I got an error like count is not a function. I will try it your code now.